# Azure Java Function (App Service Plan) can not use VPN

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans, azure-java-sdk, azure-vpn

I've deployed a Java Function with the App Service Plan on Azure and also associated a VPN (connecting back to my data center) to that App Service Container.  My application is trying to send an HTTP request to another server in my data center over the VPN but the requests fails with a "Time out" exception. If I connect directly to my data center VPN (not through Azure) it works no problem.

Also, strangely, if I recreate the function in C# it works from Azure.

1) I've tried connecting to different ports with a raw TCP socket, no luck.
2) I've dumped the list of adapters to a log and the VPN adapter doesn't show up.  Should it?

What's my next step in troubleshooting?